# What class of non linear functions can be modeled by a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

If machine is viewed as function approximation, what class of functions are modeled by a neural network?

Comment: Without any further restrictions, the answer is: any class. That's because you could have a neuron for each function in your function class.

Comment: Basically any function if you can do it, and no functions if you cannot.

Comment: @fabee: Not if your function class is infinite (most are). A reasonable assumption is with finite neurons *and* finite training samples, maybe linear in the number of neurons.

Comment: @Nimrod: That's not what the OP asked. I agree that the question gets much more interesting when phrased your way.

Answer (score 5):

[Artificial neural network: computational power (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network#Computational_power):

> **The multi-layer perceptron (MLP) is a universal function approximator**,
>   as proven by the **Cybenko theorem**. However, the proof is not
>   constructive regarding the number of neurons required or the settings
>   of the weights.
>
> Work by Hava Siegelmann and Eduardo D. Sontag has provided a proof
>   that **a specific recurrent architecture** with rational valued weights
>   (as opposed to full precision real number-valued weights) **has the full
>   power of a Universal Turing Machine** using a finite number of
>   neurons and standard linear connections. They have further shown that
>   the use of irrational values for weights results in a machine with
>   super-Turing power.

Cybenko, G.V. (1989). [Approximation by Superpositions of a Sigmoidal function](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~gvc/Cybenko_MCSS.pdf), Mathematics of Control, Signals, and Systems, Vol. 2 pp. 303–314.

Siegelmann, H.T. and Sontag, E.D. (1994). [Analog computation via neural networks](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sontag/FTP_DIR/nets-real.pdf), Theoretical Computer Science, v. 131, no. 2, pp. 331–360.

Answer (score 3):

Actually a three layer neural network can model arbitrary function with the linear and logistic functions, which was proved by Kolmogorov in 1957 (Kolmogorov, Andrei Nikolaevich. "On the representation of continuous functions of many variables by superposition of continuous functions of one variable and addition." *Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR*. Vol. 114. No. 5. 1957.).

Comment: not "arbitrary" -- see "continuous."